# C# deserialization from Java(android) header

Tags: c#, java, android, deserialization

I am working on some android project, so i need to send hashtags to the server by Header info.

So this is the server code they have for getting the hashtags.

```
 if (Request.Headers.Contains("hashtags"))
            newPost.HashTags = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
                 .Deserialize<List<string>>         (Request.Headers.GetValues("hashtags").First());
```

and i really don't know how to send ArrayList in java side to a single parametar by Headers parametar.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("hashtags", "");
```

I guess i need to serialize somehow the list and send it as string?

Please if anyone knows anything share with me, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution**

You need to post in this format

**["element1","element2","element3"]**

in simple String format.

Hope this helps!